# Applying boolean attributes in option tag conditionally

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, attributes

I'm building a `select` element dynamically from an array with jQuery and  I need to set the bool attribute `selected` on **one** of these `option` elements. If I try to pass the option

```
"selected": mycondition ? "selected" : undefined
```

the attribute ends up in the tag anyway.

How can I place the attribute *only* if I need it?

This is how I'm creating the `option` elements:

```
options.forEach(function(option){

    $("<option/>", {
       text: option.name,
       value: option.value
    }).appendTo("#mySelectElem");

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always chain `.prop()` when creating `option` object

```
options.forEach(function(option){

    $("<option/>", {
       text: option.name,
       value: option.value
    })
    .prop('selected', mycondition) //<===
    .appendTo("#mySelectElem");

});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
options.forEach(function(option){

    var opt = $("<option/>", { //<-- log option in var
       text: option.name,
       value: option.value
    }).appendTo("#mySelectElem");
    if (mycondition) opt.attr('selected', 1); //<-- conditionally add selected
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess I need to brush-up my doc reading skills... apparently, I could achieve this very simply by simply chaining the [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method:

```
  options.forEach(function(option){
    $("<option/>", {
      value: option.value,
      text: option.text
    })
      .prop("selected", function(){return mycondition ? "selected" : undefined;})
      .appendTo("#mySelectElem");
  });
```

Comment: You don't need the function, if `mycondition`is true then property will be set otherwise not. So `.prop('selected', mycondition)` is sufficient

Answer (score 0):

steps:
1.looping on array 
2.if array contain value and selected value is true then append 
test
3.else if append other options like this
test2